# WeChat browser stops CSS/JS animation when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, wechat

It happens both on iOS and Android devices. I've built some auto-played animation(and would loop for minutes) with CSS and JS. It works smoothly on desktop and all kinds of mobile browsers, but not on WeChat build-in browser.

Is there any trick to solve it, or is it because of the rendering rules of this browser?

Animations include fade in, fade out, and transition etc.

Comment: Does this problem occur with CSS or JS animations? If you are using JS what are you using for animations: setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: @MasterScrat setTimeout and setInterval. I added setTimeout in a function to call itself, to create a loop with delay. In the loop JS addClass to trigger a CSS transition. When scrolling, everything freezes.

Comment: Maybe try with requestAnimationFrame... or it really sounds like a browser limitation :-(